# Superscript ordinal in a table

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to select the ordinal on a date in a table, and change it to superscript using vb.NET. The following is my attempt:

```
Private Sub btnWordEditor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinutes.Click

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application = Nothing
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document = Nothing
    Dim OrdinalType As String = "th"

    wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\VB\Trial.docx")  
    wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2).Range.Find.Execute(FindText:=OrdinalType)
    wdDoc.Application.Selection.Font.Superscript = 9999998
 End Sub
```

This does nothing to the ordinal. What am I missing from my code to carry out this edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're searching against the Range object, but you're trying to apply the formatting to the current Selection.

If you run Find on the Selection object, then *if* something is found, the formatting will be applied to it. If what you're searching is *not* found, then the formatting will be applied to the Selection as it was when you started the search.

So searching on a Range is the right thing to do, but you need to 1) specify a Range (rather than the entire document) and 2) apply the formatting to that Range. The Range you run Find on will change to what is found and `Execute` returns `True` if it's successful.

For example:

```
Private Sub btnWordEditor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinutes.Click
  Dim wdApp As Word.Application = Nothing
  Dim wdDoc As word.Document
  Dim OrdinalType As String = "th"
  Dim rngToSearch As word.Range = Nothing
  Dim isFound As Boolean = false

  wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\VB\Trial.docx")
  rngToSearch = wdDoc.Tables(1).Range
  isFound = rngToSearch.Find.Execute(findText:=OrdinalType)
  If isFound Then
     rngToSearch.Font.Superscript = 999998
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA code would add a superscript ordinal number format to the day part of the date in your table:

```
With wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2).Range
    StrVal = Split(Split(.Text, " ")(1), ",")(0)
    .Start = .Start + InStr(.Text, StrVal) + Len(StrVal) - 1
    .End = .Start
    .InsertAfter Ordinal(Val(StrVal))
    .Font.Superscript = True
End With
End Sub

Function Ordinal(Val As Long) As String
Dim strOrd As String
If (Val Mod 100) < 11 Or (Val Mod 100) > 13 Then strOrd = Choose(Val Mod 10, "st", "nd", "rd") & ""
Ordinal = IIf(strOrd = "", "th", strOrd)
End Function
```

I'll leave it to you to do any VB.Net conversion. It is assumed the day part of the date is the second 'word' in the cell (i.e. you're using a 'month day year' sequence). If it's the first 'word' in the cell (i.e. you're using a 'day month year' sequence), change:

StrVal = Split(Split(.Text, " ")(1), ",")(0)

to:

StrVal = Split(Split(.Text, " ")(0), ",")(0)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I went with Cindy Meister's solution as I already have a function to select the ordinal, however the information is very much appreciated